# Energy of a moving system in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian

I have a question concerning the Hamiltonian operator. As I understand it, the eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian are "steady states," and their corresponding eigenvalues are the observed energy levels of those states. Steady states are such that the probability distribution $|\psi|^2$ is time-independent. Obviously correct me if I'm wrong. My confusion then arises as to the energy of a system whose probability distribution is not time-independent. Is it true that such a state has no defined energy? This feels strange to me because if you say have one electron buzzing around in one $s$-orbital with a known wavefunction and another electron in an $s$-orbital a known distance $r$ away again with a known wavefunction, it seems to me as though there would be some average energy of the system at any given instant in time, even if the electron orbitals were moving about relative to each other. In that case is there some equivalent distribution of energies that the system may have if observed? How would this distribution be calculated?

Comment: "My confusion then arises as to the energy of a system whose probability distribution is not time-independent." Generally, the stationary states wavefunctions are initially calculated as a function of position only and the time dependence is multiplied, giving the stationary state wavefunction of (x,t). Now, theorem of completeness says that ANY time dependant wavefunction can be expressed as a sum of these time dependant wavefunctions. There are simple problems in Griffiths where you finally have a time dependence in psi squared. Then you have concepts like probability current etc.

Comment: @Sidarth Oh, so are you saying that in this case the whole time-dependent function $\psi$ would be an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian as instead of an instantaneous $\psi$?

Comment: *Is it true that such a state has no defined energy?* It has various probabilities of having various energies. Energy eigenstates have a definite energy. For a superposition of eigenstates, you might measure any of their energies.

Comment: @G.Smith Oh, I see, thank you. How are each of these probabilities defined?

Comment: Defined?? Or calculated?

Comment: @G.Smith Sorry, determined would be a better word.

Comment: If the normalized wavefunction is some superposition $\sum_kc_k\psi_k$, where $\psi_k$ is a normalized energy eigenfunction with eigenvalue $E_k$, then the probability of measuring $E_k$ is $|c_k|^2$. This is the [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule), applied to energy eigenstates. When the wavefunction is just the $k^\text{th}$ energy eigenfunction, then $c_k=1$ and the probability is 1.

Comment: @G.Smith Oh, I definitely remember hearing something like that! Thank you! If the eigenfunctions are orthonormal, would it be possible to obtain $c_k$ by taking the inner product of $\psi$ and $\psi_k$ and then dividing by $|\psi_k|^2$?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: Replying to the 2nd comment in the thread, $H\psi_n= E_n\psi_n$ and in general, $\Psi =\Sigma a_n\psi_n$ . What you are saying $H\Psi= E\Psi$ is _not_ true as it would mean the system has a definite energy.